# Python: setup.py - want to make sure the correct version of python-daemonize is installed

Tags: python, python-2.7, setuptools, setup.py

As you may be aware, there are more than Python module with the name `daemon`. The version that I would like to make sure is installed is from the package [python-daemon](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/) as opposed to, for example [daemon](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/daemon/1.0).

In my `setup.py` file, I have:

```
setup(
    install_requires=['python-daemon']
)
```

However, if I run `python setup.py install` (as root of course), when the `daemon` package is already installed, `python-daemon` does not get installed.

Is there a way to make this work as I would like it to, or at least some sort of work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unfortunate that both projects picked a generic name. This makes it almost impossible to correctly specify which one you need to install.

A workaround would be to specify a minimum version; `python-daemon` is up to version 1.5.5 at the time of writing, while `daemon` only ever released version 1.0, over 3 years ago.

Pin your requirement to 1.5 and newer and `setuptools` will go looking for `python-daemon` even if `daemon` is installed:

```
setup(
    install_requires=['python-daemon >= 1.5']
)
```

This workaround will fail, of course, the day `daemon` releases a 1.5 or newer version.